# Average person or common person?

Tags: word-choice

How to say correctly: `it was too expensive for the (average|common) person`?

There are 11M results in google with "average person" and 0.5M results with "common person". So it seems like these 2 usages are valid. Is it true? Or depend on somewhat context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little bit of elitism going on here. In earlier times there were "Lords" and there were "Commoners". When Royalty was brought down a peg or two (think French Revolution in particular!) people didn't like being called "common" anymore. So although both your versions are similar, there's a stigma associated with "common" that would reduce its use.